# How do I reinstall Windows 7 through my backup?

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation

A few years ago I got Windows 7 off the official site through a special student discount. My HDD failed the other day and now I need to reinstall it.

This is what my backup looks like:

[image]

These are the files I have:

```
- expandedSetup
- DLMWin7HP64UK.exe
- setup1.box
- setup2.box
- Win7-HP-Retail-en-us-x64.exe
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to install it.

Answer (score 1):

All being equal you can make a bootable ISO and then start the reinstall, but if your files have become corrupted you may have to contact Microsoft to re-download the system (if possible).

I give you a couple of different 'How to' websites and maybe more detail than you require.

- [Windows 7 - Make bootable iso from student d/l](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/30470-make-bootable-iso-student-d-l.html)
- [How to Create and Make Bootable Windows 7 ISO from EXE Plus Setup1.Box and Setup2.Box Files](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-create-and-make-bootable-windows-7-iso-from-exe-plus-setup1-box-and-setup2-box-files/)
- [Workaround to Fix Windows 7 Unable To Create or Save New Files in the Folder Error When Unloading Box](http://www.mydigitallife.info/workaround-to-fix-windows-7-unable-to-create-or-save-new-files-in-the-folder-error-when-unloading-box/)

The examples given are carried out on a Windows Machine.

To burn the ISO, IMGburn is a good burner.

- https://superuser.com/questions/341111/recommended-iso-creator/341116#341116
- [Linux burn ISO images to Cds and CD-RWs howto](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-burn-iso-images-to-cds-and-cd-rws-howto/)

I hope things work out.

Comment: Pay attention when posting links, most of those were not correctly embedded or hard to read.

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot, so it seems to need me to have vista, like its an upgrade, rather than a full installer. because i'm currently on linux.

Comment: @neilh - it  seems to use windows system to form into a boot disk, maybe a wine iso burner environment,or something maybe ??